# Fullcalendar View Event Custom

Tags: fullcalendar

In eventRender how do I know if we are viewing
'timelineDay' or 'timelineWeek' or 'timelineMonth'
to customize the events according to the view??

```
    header: {
      left: 'prev today next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timelineMonth',
    },
```

Thanks

[image]

```
 var timeline = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name;
  if (timeline ==="timelineWeek"){
        var eventcustom =
            '<div class="wrapper-event-weekly">'
              +'<div class="box-event-weekly box-event-ico col-1">'
                +'<i class="'+e.icon+' fa-2x"></i>'
                +'</div>'  
              +'<div class="box-event-weekly box-event-title col-10">'
                +'<span>'+e.odldesc+'</span></br>'
                +'<span><b>'+e.odlnum+'</b></span>'
              +'</div>'
              +'<div class="box-event-weekly box-event-info col-1">'
                +'<i class="'+note+' fa-lg"></i>'
              +'</div>'
            +'</div>'; 
        }      
  else if (timeline ==="timelineMonth"){      
        var eventcustom =
            '<div class="wrapper-event-month">'
              +'<div class="box-event-month box-event-ico col-12">'
                +'<i class="'+e.icon+' fa-2x"></i>'
                +'</div>'  
              +'<div class="box-event-month box-event-title col-12">'
                +'<span>'+e.odldesc+'</span></br>'
                +'<span><b>'+e.odlnum+'</b></span>'
              +'</div>'
              +'<div class="box-event-month box-event-info col-12">'
                +'<i class="'+note+' fa-lg"></i>'
              +'</div>'
            +'</div>';   
          }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "customise the events according to the view"? The day week and month views are just to control how much time is visible on the calendar at once. You would show the same events for all of them, because they are just different size windows looking onto the same scene.

Comment: Risolto con 
var timeline = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').name;
if (timeline ==="timelineWeek"){
Here custom my event week
}      
else if (timeline ==="timelineMonth"){
Here custom my event Month
}

Comment: Sure...but did you understand my explanation? Why would you display different events just because it's month or week view? It's just a different window onto the same data. It makes no sense. And you can't do it because the events are loaded asynchronously from the view, so by the time you've loaded the view, it's too late to tell it which events to load (and vice-versa). And if you re-load the events it will re-load the view, potentially causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes but I use it in eventRender, if you change from week to month he calls this event and does not generate infinite loop, I only change the template of how you view in week or month

Comment: You see. I Add image

Comment: In that picture, your event data appears to be the same in both the week and month cases. I don't know what you want me to understand from that picture?

Comment: yes the data are the same I changed something to stack them in a different way instead of using the css I worked with the DIVs

Comment: So you solved your issue then? Or is there still a question? Now I'm confused about what you actually want

Comment: i really solved thanks

Comment: Ok So you wanted to customise the _appearance_ of the events, not the event data itself. That wasn't clear from your original question. That's why I was suggesting it wasn't possible. I thought you wanted to show a different set of events in each view, not simply change how they look.